# Saving Value of a Checkbox to the Database in Android

Tags: android

I have a checkbox in my activity.

When the user press the Save button and leave the checkbox ***`unchecked`***, `instead of '0'`, it will be saved as ***`NO`***.

But when the user ***`ticked the checkbox`*** and save it, `instead of '1'`, it will be saved as ***`YES`***.

Comment: Actually, I don't have any fledged code for this one. I don't know how to do it since it was my first to encounter a checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CheckBox c;
String SaveString="No";
//Initialize CheckBox
c.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean checked) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(checked)
        {
            SaveString="Yes";
        }
        else
        {
            SaveString="No";
        }
    }
});
```

Now,

```
 SaveDatabase(SaveString);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  btnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  

    CheckBox c = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);


    if (c.isChecked())
     { // save to String Variable for yes, strCheckBox="yes";
     }
    else
    {  // save to String Variable for No, strCheckBox="no";
    }

   //Code for Save to database

}
    });
```